# Set up toggle for file ignore patterns with Telescope

Tags: neovim

I'm new to NeoVim and Lua in general. I'm looking into setting up a keybinding so that I can toggle ignore files - because sometime I want to be able to sneak into those ignore files from time-to-time.

Kind of in the same way we'd press `I` to toggle hidden files in nvim-tree.

I've tried setting up a keybinding to do this when I press `<leader>-fi` the config will be updated.

---

I've set up my configs using nvchad, and have tried updating telescope.lua to the following.

```lua
local file_ignore_patterns = { "node_modules" }
local options = {
  defaults = {
    -- ...
    file_ignore_patterns = file_ignore_patterns,
}

function _G.TelescopeToggleIgnore()
    if (options.defaults.file_ignore_patterns == file_ignore_patterns) then
      options.defaults.file_ignore_patterns = {}
    else
      options.defaults.file_ignore_patterns = file_ignore_patterns
    end
end
vim.cmd([[
  command! TelescopeToggleIgnore lua _G.TelescopeToggleIgnore()
]])

return options
```

However, nothing actually changes when I try and search for what would otherwise be a hidden file. I'm guessing I need to do something to refresh Telescope or something, but I'm not sure how to do that.